Reconstruct points on a sphere from matrix of dot-products
Suppose I have a matrix of pairwise dot products corresponding to vectors on a sphere. How do I reconstruct these vectors (up to a rotation?).
Below is a solution that reconstructs a set of vectors using SVD, but these don't lie on a sphere.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
On[Assert];
{m, d} = {10, 10};
X = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, d}];
gram = X\[Transpose] . X;
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[gram];

vecs = Table[Sqrt[S[[i, i]]] U[[All, i]], {i, Range@Length@U}];
Assert[Norm[Total[{#}\[Transpose] . {#} & /@ vecs] - gram] < 10^-10]
Assert[AllTrue[vecs, Norm[#] == 1. &]]


I'm wondering if CholeskyDecomposition could be useful here. It will have the same problem that the vectors won't be normalized however but maybe there's some smart way to scale each vector...sorry if this comment isn't super helpful.

Row vectors of X are normalized. So, gram should be X. X\[Transpose] ?

Do you want to deal with $m=d$ cases only?

Vectors on a sphere are still vectors. Not clear why your solution cannot be applied to the vectors on a sphere. Do you also need to determine the radius of the sphere?

@yarchik I need the Assert to pass in the code sample

@DanielHuber not quite, the existing solution in question uses eigenvectors, but they don't lie on a sphere, and if you normalize, they won't add up to original matrix

Can you kindly precise you question? I have in mind the following.  If $m=3$ and $d=3$ (thre vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$), then we have a system of 3+Binomial[3,2]==6 equations in 9 unknowns. The set of its solution is infinite in the general case.

Even taking into account the OP's "up tp rotations" such a reconstruction in 3D is impossible: a rotation is defined by two parameters, but  the solutions depends on 3=9-6 parameters.

Is this a Mathematica question or a mathematics question?

Matrix square root of the Gram matrix solves your problem.
I assume that $m\geq d$ and input vectors are rows of the matrix X.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
{m, d} = {20, 10};
X = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, d}];
gram = X . Transpose[X];

sqrtGram = MatrixPower[gram, 1/2];
ker = NullSpace[sqrtGram];
vecs = If[Length[ker] == 0, sqrtGram,
   proj = NullSpace[ker]; Transpose[proj.sqrtGram]];

The variable vecs contains reconstructed vectors. Check that they are normalized:
Norm[#] == 1. & /@ vecs

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

Check that their pairwise dot products are equal to gram:
Union[Flatten[Chop[vecs . Transpose[vecs] - gram]]]
(* {0} *) 

An orthogonal matrix $P$ which transform X to vecs:
P = Inverse[X[[;; d]]] . vecs[[;; d]];
OrthogonalMatrixQ[P]
(* True *)

Union[Flatten[Chop[vecs - X . P]]]
(* {0} *)

Remark
(1) Every positive (semi)definite symmetric matrix $G$ has its square root $H$, which is also positive (semi)definite symmetric matrix: $G=H^2$. In this problem, we take the matrix of inner products $X X^T$ as $G$, so its square root $H$ satisfy $X X^T = H^2=H H^T$. Therefore $H$ is the candidate for the original $X$. Of course, there is an $d$-dimensional rotation ambiguity because $X$ and $XP$ gives the same Gram matrix for any $P\in O(d)$.
(2) If $n>d$, the row vectors of $X$ are linearly dependent, so the   $n\times n$ Gram matrix $G$ is singular. Since all the vectors in the null-space of $G$ are orthogonal to everything, they must be projected out in order to recover $d$-dimensional vectors from $n$ dimensional row-vectors of $\sqrt{G}$.

In order to reconstruct 10 vectors in 10 dimensions, we deal with a system of 55 equations in 100 unknowns. Such systems have infinite sets of the solutions in the general case.

@user64494 You are right. If $X$ is a solution, then $XP$ is also a solution for all orthogonal matrix $P$.   So there is $dim O(d)= 100-55=45$ dimensional ambiguity. That's why OP says up to rotations. In such cases, the optimization approach often fail or extremely slow, and needs special care. So I avoided optimization approach and took direct method.

A. Kato: Thank you. I got it.

To reconstruct unit vectors from their pairwise dot products (Gram matrix) while ensuring they lie on a sphere, we can set up and solve an optimization problem that enforces the unit norm constraints.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
On[Assert];
{m, d} = {10, 10};

(* Generate random unit vectors *)
Xorig = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, d}];

(* Compute the Gram matrix *)
gram = Xorig . Transpose[Xorig];

(* Define variables *)
vars = Flatten@Table[x[i, j], {i, m}, {j, d}];

(* Define constraints: unit norms *)
normConstraints = Table[Sum[x[i, j]^2, {j, d}] == 1,{i, m}];

(* Define the objective function *)
objective = Sum[
  (Sum[x[i, k] x[j, k], {k, d}] - gram[[i, j]])^2,
  {i, m}, {j, i + 1, m}
];

(* Initial guess using eigenvalue decomposition *)
{eigvals, eigvecs} = Eigensystem[gram];
positiveIndices = Flatten@Position[eigvals, _?(# > 0 &)];
eigvalsPos = eigvals[[positiveIndices]];
eigvecsPos = eigvecs[[All, positiveIndices]];
Xinit = eigvecsPos . DiagonalMatrix[Sqrt[eigvalsPos]];
XinitNorm = Normalize /@ Xinit;

(* Create initial values for optimization *)
initialValues = Flatten[Table[
  {x[i, j], XinitNorm[[i, j]]},
  {i, m}, {j, d}
], 1];

(* Solve the optimization problem *)
solution = FindMinimum[
  Evaluate@{objective, normConstraints},
  initialValues
];

(* Extract the optimized vectors *)
optimizedVectors = Table[
  Table[x[i, j], {j, d}] /. solution[[2]],
  {i, m}
];

(* Verify unit norms *)
Assert[AllTrue[optimizedVectors, Chop[Norm[#] - 1., 10^-6] == 0 &]];

(* Verify reconstructed Gram matrix *)
reconstructedGram = optimizedVectors . Transpose[optimizedVectors];
differenceNorm = Norm[reconstructedGram - gram];
Print["Difference Norm: ", differenceNorm];
Assert[differenceNorm < 10^-5];


Difference Norm: 8.51416*10^-7

This method reconstructs the vectors by minimizing the difference between the computed dot products and the given Gram matrix, subject to the constraint that each vector has unit length. The solution is unique up to an orthogonal transformation.
Probably one possible way to visualize the quality of reconstruction will be the following.
(* Combine original and reconstructed vectors *)
combinedVectors = Join[Xorig, optimizedVectors];

(* Perform PCA *)
pcaResult = PrincipalComponents[combinedVectors];

(* Extract projections *)
pcaOriginal = pcaResult[[1 ;; m, 1 ;; 3]];
pcaReconstructed = pcaResult[[m + 1 ;; 2 m, 1 ;; 3]];

(* 3D Scatter plot *)
Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[pcaOriginal, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.6]}],
  ListPointPlot3D[pcaReconstructed, PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.6]}],
  PlotLabel -> "PCA Projection"
]



In order to reconstruct 10 vectors in 10 dimensions, we deal with a system of 55 equations in 100 unknowns. Such systems have infinite sets of the solutions in the general case

Your claim "The solution is unique up to an orthogonal transformation" does not correspond to reality:  the solutions depend on 45=100-55 parameters, but the rotations in  10 dimensions depend on 9 parameters (think of hyper-spherical coordinates).

@user64494 four dimensional rotations are 6 dimensional. Can we specified using two angles of rotation into planes of rotation with each plane has two parameters each https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space

@YaroslavBulatov: Sorry, don't understand it. Can you kindly elaborate your comment and question with details?

@user64494 spaces of $d\times d$ orthogonal matrices has $O(d^2)$ dimensions, not $O(d)$. Here's a derivation showing that a subspace of this space has $d(d-2)/4$ dimensions. That's a lower bound. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4961424/dimension-of-on-restricted-to-fixed-rotation-angle

@YaroslavBulatov: Thank you. I need some time to think about it.

Note that have spherical symmetry as well as symmetry relative to mirroring at the coordinate planes. We can therefore reconstruct the original vectors only up to a rotation and inversion of some components.
To keep thing simple, we make only a 3D example. To define the 3 vectors, we choose v10 along the x axis and v20 in the x-y plane  and v30 arbitrary on a sphere with radius 2:
SeedRandom[1];
r0 = 2;
v10 = {r0, 0, 0};
v20 = r0  Normalize[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0}];
v30 = r0  Normalize[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}];

The matrix of dot products is then:
m0 = {v10, v20, v30};
dm0 = Outer[Dot, m0, m0, 1];

Now to reconstruct the original vectors we choose vectors and the matrix of dot products:
v1 = {r, 0, 0};
v2 = {l2x, l2y, 0};
v3 = {l3x, l3y, l3z};
m = {v1, v2, v3};
dm = Outer[Dot, {v1, v2, v3}, {v1, v2, v3}, 1] // Chop;

Now we request that dm==dm0 and r>0
eq = Table[dm[[i, j]] == dm0[[i, j]], {i, 3}, {j, i}] /. 
     True -> Nothing // Flatten // Chop;
eq = Join[eq, {r > 0}];
sol = {v1, v2, v3} /. 
  NSolve[eq, {l2x, l2y, l3x, l3y, l3z, r}, Reals][[1]]

{{2., 0, 0}, {1.26519, 1.54897, 0}, {1.16233, 1.25334, -1.03833}}

These are the original vectors. Note however, it is possible that some components can be negated due to symmetry.
To check that we can reproduce the original dot matrix:
Outer[Dot, sol, sol, 1] == dm0

True


Interesting, but how about the case of 10 vectors in 10 dimensions?

Same strategy, First vector {r,0,0,...}, second vector: {l21,l22,0,0...$, third vector: {l31,l32,l33,0,0....l} e.t.c

DanielHuber: Thank you. Did you try to realize it?  My try with x[1]=Table[x[1,j],{j,1,3}]; x[2]=...  and to NSolve  the system {x[1].x[1]==1,x[2].x[2]==1,x[3].x[3],x[1].x[2]==-0.2,x[1].x[3]==0.5,x[2].x[3]==-0.1, x[1]<={1,1,1},x[1].>={-1,-1,-1},...} crashed  my comp.

DanielHuber: Also {v1, v2, v3} /. NSolve[eq, {l2x, l2y, l3x, l3y, l3z, r}, Reals] from your code  outputs {{{2., 0, 0}, {1.26519, -1.54897,     0}, {1.16233, -1.25334, -1.03833}}, {{2., 0,     0}, {1.26519, -1.54897, 0}, {1.16233, -1.25334, 1.03833}}, {{2., 0,     0}, {1.26519, 1.54897, 0}, {1.16233, 1.25334, -1.03833}}, {{2., 0,     0}, {1.26519, 1.54897, 0}, {1.16233, 1.25334, 1.03833}}}, confirming the impossibility to reconstruct vectors.

I think my explanation is rather detailed and it works.

The main defect of your approach is the following: putting v1 = {r, 0, 0}; v2 = {l2x, l2y, 0}; v3 = {l3x, l3y, l3z};, you exclude the infinite set of cases, for example, v1 = {r, 0, 0}; v2 = {l2x, l2y,12x-12y}; v3 = {l3x, l3y, l3z}; in your notations.
